# pg_relation_size command is not providing size

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to find size of a table in posgreSQL. I am using following command but it is giving me 0 as an output. Could you please inform me how can I get the size of a table?

INPUT:

```
select pg_relation_size('tableName');
```

OUTPUT:

```
pg_relation_size 

  0

(1 row)
```

Comment: Does the table `tableName` has data?

Comment: yes, tableName contains data

Comment: Try using `pg_total_relation_size` instead of `pg_relation_size`.

Comment: I tried that but it was not working too.

Comment: Maybe you have two tables with the same name, one empty in the search empty and one non-empty which is not in search path? Have you tried including schema, e.g. `select pg_relation_size('public.tableName');`?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well but still getting the same result.

Comment: tableName is a foreign table copied from Oracle DB

Answer (score 2):

I know this is ancient but I just ran into the same issue.
It was due to the fact that the table is a partitioned one, so technically it doesn't have a real size. To get the combined size of all the partitions, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920864/get-table-size-of-partitioned-table-postgres-10).

Or you could simply make use of the inheritance catalog like:

```
SELECT count(*) AS child_amount, pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_relation_size(inhrelid::regclass))) AS child_size
FROM pg_inherits 
WHERE inhparent='tableName'::regclass;
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `tableName` is a view.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW dummy AS SELECT 1;
SELECT pg_relation_size('dummy');
```

Result:

```
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
                0
(1 row)
```